# Split() in VBA gives Type Mismatch error

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm have some error in this code below, please someone can help me..the VBA sad me that the instrument is a invalid qualifier on the line that I get his lenght, when I use the function len() don't have any error, but on function split happens!the VBA sad me that the type mismatch.

```
Sub Getinstrument()
 Dim instrument As String
 Dim splitinstrument() As String
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim removespax As Integer
 Dim tam As Integer
 removespax = -1
 instrument = Range("E3")
 splitinstrument() = Split(instrument)
 tam = instrument.Lenght - 1
 For i = 0 To tam
    If splitinstrument(i) <> ""  Then
       removespax = removespax + 1
       splitinstrument(removespax) = splitinstrument(i)
    End If
 Next
 ReDim Preserve splitinstrument(removespax)
 MsgBox splitinstrument()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want `Tam` to loop through the array, you actually want this

```
tam = UBound(splitinstrument)
```

instead of

```
tam = instrument.Lenght - 1
```

Comment: To get the length of the string, you would use Len(instrument), not instrument.Lenght.  instrument.Lenght isn't valid in any sense for vba, unless instrument was an object with a "Lenght" property.

Comment: @KevinFrancis: I doubt OP wants the length :)

Comment: Excellent point.  The base message I was trying to communicate was... if instrument is a string variable, then the line with instrument.Lenght would not compile at all.

Comment: Ok guys..thanks very much!..now I have other problem, when I use the  msgbox the VBA say that the type mismatch..do you know why this happens?

Comment: @MoisesBarbosa Different question = Different thread :) You can't ask different questions in the same thread ;)